# tuleap alm after upgrade not able to login

Tags: php, apache, tuleap

the Tuleap is running on CentOS the OS is upgraded after that not able to login to tuleap

when i check the logs in httpd/error.log it says

```
[Tue Feb 07 14:56:38 2017] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/tmp/tuleap_cache/sess_u9c6qfrtm6715t9qmjs2idrbq4, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/include/LoaderScheduler.php on line 45
[Tue Feb 07 14:56:38 2017] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] PHP Notice:  DB error ==> SELECT * FROM session WHERE id = 0 AND time + 15811200 > 1486459598 @@ /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/dao/include/DataAccessObject.class.php at line 96 in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/dao/include/DataAccessObject.class.php on line 156
[Tue Feb 07 14:56:38 2017] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getRow() on a non-object in /usr/share/tuleap/src/common/dao/include/DataAccessObject.class.php on line 110
[Tue Feb 07 14:56:38 2017] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/tmp/tuleap_cache/sess_u9c6qfrtm6715t9qmjs2idrbq4, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Feb 07 14:56:38 2017] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/tmp/tuleap_cache) in Unknown on line 0
```

Edit

When i run the

`/usr/lib/forgeupgrade/bin/forgeupgrade --config=/etc/codendi/forgeupgrade/config.ini update`

giving error as below :

```
ERROR - An error occured while adding svn_immutable_tags table.
```

Comment: It seems you have an ownership issue, what's the results of `ls -ld /var/tmp/tuleap_cache` and `ps -aux | grep httpd` ?

Comment: I think it's because I upgraded perl by force so.. the permission issue is solved